# How to add api to the apifood.co

Tags: api

What way I should use to add our own API to the directory http://apifood.co/?
I looked on the website but didn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments in the ["P" link](https://www.producthunt.com/tech/apifood) found the top left of the website, Nicolas Le Roux, the site's creator states:

> The data comes from publicapis.com, programmableweb.com and me :)

[PublicApis.com](https://www.publicapis.com/) has an [Add API](https://www.publicapis.com/add) page for submissions. Add your API there and it in theory should filter through.

You could also just contact the site's creator directly, all of his contact links are there too.